# Editing content in an attached template in Microsoft Word

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word

I'm trying to create a macro that creates a Userform, which in turn creates a document based on a given template and the data input into the Userform.

For example, the document might be a letter, with the content:

"Dear @name, thank you for choosing us!"

And I want to dynamically change the value @name with input from the Userform.

I've tried experimenting with attaching Document Templates, but I don't know how to manipulate the content inside the template or create the document from the given template in the first place.

How do I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `DocVariable` field for the name, e.g. "addressee", then you can simply set it like this (replace `ActiveDocument` with your document object):

```
Dim docvar As Variable, doc As Document

Set doc = ActiveDocument
docvar = doc.Variables("addressee")
docvar.Value = "Mr.Smith"
doc.Fields.Update
```